# Permutations in Python with different options for each position

Tags: python, permutation, combinatorics

I'm trying to write a solver for a sudoku-like puzzle, and at some point I want to find all possible combinations for a row. A row must contain digits from 1 to 6 with no duplicates. In general, there would be 6! = 720 combinations for a row. But since I already narrowed down my options, the list of possible choices would look something like this:

row = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 6], [1, 2, 4], [1, 3, 4, 5, 6], [2, 3, 4, 5]]

Or like this, with some numbers already found:

row = [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], 5, 6, [1, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4]]

The solution I came up with involves using itertools product function to get all possible combinations with duplicates and then sifting through the resulting list to remove all options with duplicates:

```py
from itertools import product

def get_permutations(row):
    # this line is needed to turn ints (digits that are already found)
    # into sets with the length of 1:
    row = [s.copy() if isinstance(s, set) else {s} for s in row]

    # this is where we get all possible permutations with duplicates:
    prod = product(*row)
    # in this example, we have 2880 permutations with duplicates

    without_duplicates = [value for value in prod if len(value) == len(set(value))]
    # without duplicates, there's only 32 variations
    return without_duplicates

r = [{1, 2, 3, 4}, {1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3, 6}, {1, 2, 4}, {1, 3, 4, 5, 6}, {2, 3, 4, 5}]
perm = get_permutations(r)
```

The problem with this method is that we create thousands of permutations only to narrow them down to a few dozen. It works relatively well for a 6x6 puzzle, but will be too inefficient for bigger ones, where thousands turn into millions. So maybe there's a way not to include duplicates in our list to begin with.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I updated the description and included a code sample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you incrementally build up your cartesian products, you can strip out the duplicate entries before they grow exponentially. Here is a code snippet doing exactly that:

```py
from itertools import product
from collections.abc import Iterable

def uniq_prod(sets):
    result = [()]
    
    for selection in sets:
        result = [tup + (x,) for tup in result for x in selection.difference(tup)]
        
    return result

def get_perms_fast(row):
    if not row:
        return []
    return uniq_prod([set(s) if isinstance(s, Iterable) else {s} for s in row])
```

Running it on your example input:

```py
>>> row = [{1, 2, 3, 4}, {1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3, 6}, {1, 2, 4}, {1, 3, 4, 5, 6}, {2, 3, 4, 5}]
>>> print(get_perms_fast(row))
[(1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 5), (1, 2, 6, 4, 3, 5), (1, 2, 6, 4, 5, 3), (1, 3, 2, 4, 6, 5), (1, 3, 6, 2, 4, 5), (1, 3, 6, 2, 5, 4), (1, 3, 6, 4, 5, 2), (2, 1, 3, 4, 6, 5), (2, 1, 6, 4, 3, 5), (2, 1, 6, 4, 5, 3), (2, 3, 1, 4, 6, 5), (2, 3, 6, 1, 4, 5), (2, 3, 6, 1, 5, 4), (2, 3, 6, 4, 1, 5), (3, 1, 2, 4, 6, 5), (3, 1, 6, 2, 4, 5), (3, 1, 6, 2, 5, 4), (3, 1, 6, 4, 5, 2), (3, 2, 1, 4, 6, 5), (3, 2, 6, 1, 4, 5), (3, 2, 6, 1, 5, 4), (3, 2, 6, 4, 1, 5), (4, 1, 3, 2, 6, 5), (4, 1, 6, 2, 3, 5), (4, 1, 6, 2, 5, 3), (4, 2, 3, 1, 6, 5), (4, 2, 6, 1, 3, 5), (4, 2, 6, 1, 5, 3), (4, 3, 1, 2, 6, 5), (4, 3, 2, 1, 6, 5), (4, 3, 6, 1, 5, 2), (4, 3, 6, 2, 1, 5)]
```

Comment: Why not just start with `result = [()]`?

Comment: @KellyBundy because of the edge case around an empty `row`. For some reason I was thinking uniq_prod was the public function, meaning it'd have to handle sets/lists/generators/etc., which is why I didn't just pass it a list and early exit with a check.

Comment: Updated to use your simplification, and return an empty list instead of raising StopIteration on empty row, which admittedly didn't quite sit well with me anyways

Comment: Actually you got that edge case wrong. If `row` is empty, you should return `[()]`, not `[]`. So just remove that `if not row: return []`.

Comment: Thanks. This sped up my code significantly. Btw, I think returning an empty list in case of a missing row is a nice touch, I won't be removing that part.